# Route www.<subdomain> to <subdomain>?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I have a domain that needs to redirect **from** `www.subdomain.domain.net` **to** `subdomain.domain.net`

I know this is possible, but how? It isn't automatic. What DNS records do I need to update?

Comment: Are you hosting this web site by your self. Are you using apache ?

Comment: Nope, shared hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your DNS with a CNAME record.

```
NAME                TYPE   VALUE    
foo.example.com.    CNAME  bar.example.com.
```

or in your case:

```
NAME                     TYPE   VALUE    
www.subdomain.domain.net CNAME  subdomain.domain.net
```

For more information, look at [wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) description

Answer (score 3):

If you just want www.subdomain.domain.net to work then just setup DNS and setup the web server to respond to that host header as well as the normal one.

If you want www.subdomain.domain.net to actually change in the browsers URL bar to subdomain.domain.net that'll require the DNS change and the web server being configured to return 301 responses along with the new URL to redirect to.